# roman numerals with polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, roman

[image]In the short example below I have an issue with incorrect writing the roman numerals (in frontmatter page numbering and in the plain text). Both issues come from using the polyglossia and setting the main language to Serbian. Can someone help me to have 'normal' roman numbers in this document. (Please do this without a suggestion to change \setmainfont into something else.)

```
\documentclass[10pt, b5paper]{book}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}


\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}[Mapping=ascii-to-serbian, Script=Cyrillic, Language=Serbian]


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chhh}

\section{Seccc}

texttttttttt \rom{3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess the issue you are having relies on **which characters** are used for the roman numerals (perhaps those assigned to Serbian?). If so, I reccomend you clarify this in your question.

Comment: I have just tested the code as it is, but am not getting Serbian characters. Is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: The font mapping applies to each character using the font. You have to define a new font family, using the same font, but with the standard font mapping and use that when you want Latin characters.

Comment: logo_writer, you are right about 'which characters'. Now I added a picture in the initial question. You will see that the contents-page is enumerated by cyrillic letter I (I need Latin), and similarly for the roman numerals in the text (see the section title).

Comment: Now, I realise that if I add the line \newfontfamily{\ef}{DejaVu Serif} and then modify the corresponding line to \newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\ef\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@} this resolves roman numerals in the text, but NOT those in frontmatter page numbering.